# Netbeans IDE 8.2 C++ output window issue

Tags: c++, netbeans

When I am trying to compile any code in the ide the output window text has some weird letter spacing, please help how to fix it
The images are below

1. [The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3H5r.png)
2. [Settings of output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22s2b.png)
3. [Setting of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv36U.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and what worked for me was :

Go to Tools >> Options >> Miscellaneous >> Output tab

Choose the font you want, I chose Monospaced 11.

Go to the Terminal tab and choose the button next to the font name, this will open the Font Chooser dialogue.  Choose the same font as before and also click on the Default font button.

Click OK.

That might help.  It worked for me.